# Unity SetActive doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got some problem. I am trying to hide a`GameObject` using `SetActive(false);` But the object is still shown in the game.

Here is the code:

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject a;
    public GameObject b;


    void Start () {
        a.SetActive (false);
        b.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that SetActive (true); is not being from another Update function?

Comment: Ok. Can you post a picture/screenshot that shows your object a and b and the slot on the script they are connected to. I've never seen a problem like this before...

Comment: I just have solved the problem. I created empty object and set object A to child. Thanks a lot

Comment: glad you solved it

Answer (score 0):

(Going off some presumptions here, please correct if this is not your scenario)

In order for this to work, `a` and `b` will need to be `GameObject`s in your actual scene. This will not work with prefabs because prefabs aren't ever in the scene, they're copied in.

Comment: A and B is objects, for example, I created a simple cube and sphere, write the script to disable them and attached script to the parent object, as the result, A and B aren't disabled